# Assign string to dereference of register inline

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I have an `$rsi` that is currently a pointer to a string and I'd like to change the value of that string using C in-line assembly.

The code I have now is:

```c
char *my_str = "abc123";
asm("mov %[changed_string], %%rsi\n" :: [changed_string] "r" (my_str));
```

This is obviously loading the VALUE of my_str into `$rsi`. I know this translates to assembly as:

```
mov rsi, my_str
```

and if I were to examine the value of `$rsi` it would be `my_str`, effectively overwriting the pointer, which is not what I want to do.

I know in assembly I can accomplish what I want by adding brackets around
`$rsi`:

```
mov [rsi], my_str
```

But when I do that in C I'm met with an error:

```c
asm("mov %[changed_string], %%[rsi]\n" :: [changed_string] "r" (my_str));

Error: bad register name: %[rsi]
```

Comment: That gives me the new error: `Error: Invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 '[%rsi]'

Comment: Do you want to change what `rsi` is pointing to or do you want to change the contents of the memory it is currently pointing to?

Comment: I want to change the value of the string pointed to by `$rsi`

Comment: You don't want to use `mov` to change the value of a string. You will need to set up source and destination registers and a count and use one of the `movs` instructions. But you will also need to ensure that you don't make the string longer. A bit more explanation of what you are trying to do, and why, would help.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm honestly just messing around with function hooking and trying to learn about it and assembly. I'm hooking an assignment `myClass::out_str = my_str`. Would it be better to replace the pointer in $rsi with one that points to my_str? If so, what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Note also that registers cannot be assumed to keep their values between inline assembly statements.  From how your inline assembly looks, it is most likely used incorrectly and will break.

Comment: I think that should throw some logical errors also , because you are trying to modify a string that's normally stored in ROM or flash (non-volatile) , unless you explicitly said in your linker script to store the code into the RAM